# TideSDK and dependency on SDK

Tags: html, tidesdk

I'm very very new to HTML5 programming, so forgive me if I ask a strange question. I'm looking for a good tool to write apps the can be run on iPhone, Android and the most known webbrowsers on a desktop. I came across TideSDK and I was a bit confused by the fact that it has SDK in the title. Does this mean that the SDK is part of anything I will create with it?

Do I have to distribute the SDK along with the App I create and wouldn't that be a problem when wanting to freely distribute my application?

Regards
Gabrie

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two ways to build the application
1) with package.
   With package works as stand alone application without any dependencies or anything other things installed.
2) without package.
   The think you were saying is right. They need to have modules to be installed.